# Why are winsock types undeclared when compiling C++ with winsock, cmake and mingw?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, mingw, winsock

I am porting an application I wrote on linux to Windows. I am trying to cross-compile on linux for windows. Part of porting the application includes the usage of the winsock library. In order to cross-compile, I decided to use x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.

I followed the instructions provided on cmakes official documentation on [cross-compiling](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html), where I specify a toolchain file tc-mingw.cmake.

**test.cpp:**

```
#include "winsock2.h"


int main()
{
  pollfd poll_fd;

  return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Multi3D)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17 -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-std=c++17 -Wall -O3")

find_library(WSOCK32_LIBRARY wsock32 HINTS /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/)
find_library(WS2_32_LIBRARY ws2_32 HINTS /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/)

if (NOT WSOCK32_LIBRARY OR NOT WS2_32_LIBRARY)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find winsock libraries")
else()
  message(STATUS "Windows libs found: ${WSOCK32_LIBRARY} ${WS2_32_LIBRARY}")
endif()

add_executable(testbinary test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(testbinary
                      ${WSOCK32_LIBRARY}
                      ${WS2_32_LIBRARY})
```

**tc-mingw.cmake**

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Calling with

> cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../tc-mingw.cmake ..

Finds the libraries

> -- Windows libs found: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libwsock32.a /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libws2_32.a

but oddly results in the compilation error

```
> error: ‘pollfd’ was not declared in this scope
    6 |   pollfd poll_fd;
```

And so, winsock types seem to not be declared when compiling with my build setup. I can't figure out why! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I checked under /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/, which should be where the includes are, and all the correct files are there, including winsock2.h.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but please take some time to read [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Researching this issue actually introduced me to this difference for the first time! I wasn't aware that there was one.

It turns out that defining   #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 fixes my issue. It appears that the detected version of windows my mingw compiler uses is incompatible with many winsock2 types?

Comment: Unless you found the solution here on Stack Overflow, you should write an answer about that (please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)). Otherwise, and if possible, please either close the question as a duplicate or delete it to avoid duplicates. :)

Comment: I will refrain from writing an answer as I do not wish to add a 'bad answer'.

I don't understand _WIN32_WINNT, nor do I understand potential consequences that may or may not arise due to this manual definition. As such, I don't want to lead people to unwittingly include buggy code in their project!

If someone with knowledge on _WIN32_WINNT could confirm that my comment above is an acceptable solution, that'd be great.

Comment: These are the versions of windows from which the code can run. "0x0600" is for windows vista. Earlier versions do not have the appropriate dlls for the code in question.

Comment: Winsock doesn't define the `pollfd` type, because it doesn't have the `poll()` function to begin with. That is a POSIX function, not a Windows function. Winsock has a (buggy) `WSAPoll()` function, which uses a `WSAPOLLFD` type instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `winsock2.h` is a system library, so it makes more sense to use angle brackets instead of double quotes.

So `test.cpp` will should look like this:

```cpp
#include <winsock2.h>


int main()
{
  pollfd poll_fd;

  return 0;
}
```

If I build that with `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -O3 test.cpp -o test.exe -lws2_32` with a recent version if MinGW-w64 it succeeds (apart from `warning: unused variable 'poll_fd' [-Wunused-variable]`, which makes sense).

Latest version is 12.2.0.

You can check the version you're using by running `g++ --version`.

If you're cross-building on Linux you should replace `g++` in the commands above with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-win32`